# JavaScript module from factory design instead of class

Tags: javascript, module, factory

I am trying to learn myself JavaScript recently, and I am trying to understand the factory design pattern. Doing that I come across this problem.

I have a simple logger class which I export as a module, this class extends the events module class.

```
const EventClass = require('events');

class Logger extends EventClass { 
    printSomething(something) {
        console.log(something);    
        this.emit('logged', { context: 'not implemented' });
    }
}    
module.exports = Logger;
```

And it catches the event here

```
const EventClass = require('events');
const Logger = require('./logger');

logger.on('logged', (arg) => {
    console.log('Listener called', arg);
});
logger.printSomething('something');
```

How would I be able to re-create this scenario using the factory design pattern instead of making the class extend from the events class?

Here is my shot:

```
const EventClass = require('events');
const eventObject = new EventClass();

const Log = function () {
    const log = {};
    log.eventObject; // HERE I TRY TO SET THE eventObject TO THE LOG
    log.printSomething = (something) => {
        console.log(something);
        eventObject.emit('logged', { context: 'not implemented' });
    }
    return log;
}

const loggerObject = Log();
module.exports = loggerObject;
```

And

```
const EventClass = require('events');
const logger = require('./logger');
logger.eventObject.on('logged', (arg) => {
    console.log('Listener called', arg);
});
logger.printSomething('something');
```

I thought that creating the instance of the events class inside scope of the function, I would be able to do `logger.eventObject`. And I do not know how to make it a nested object.

Stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\min hjemmeside\index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

How do I make the eventObject accessible after exporting the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do not answer my own questions - but I found a solution.

```
const EventClass = require('events');
let eventObject = new EventClass();

const Log = function () {
    const log = {};
    log.eventObject = new EventClass(); //I ended up assigning the eventObject like this
    log.printSomething = (something) => {
        console.log(something);
        eventObject.emit('message is logged', { context: 'not implemented' });
    }
    return log;
}
module.exports = Log;
```

I will still accept an answer if an in depth explanation why this works contrary the previous.